# mac terminal installs vs allow apps downloaded from

Tags: macos

On mac, in security & privacy, we have either Allow apps downloaded from:  App Store or App Store and Identified developers.

If I want to be in terminal installing eg cocoapods, homebrew, node, etc, do the setting in paragraph one matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Simple executables and other programs downloaded via brew, node, etc. don't qualify as OS X "Apps" and aren't subject to that setting. Only Xcode developed, code-signed programs packaged into a `<program.name>.app` bundle are affected by that setting.